# Limiting the number of Shiny sessions per process to 1

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server

Is it possible to limit the number of sessions per process to **1** in Shiny Server Open Source?

Answer (score 0):

I have found this to be possible using the Simple Scheduler in Shiny Server Open Source.

From [Shiny Server Manual](https://docs.rstudio.com/shiny-server/#simple-scheduler)

```
location / {
  # Define the scheduler to use for this location
  simple_scheduler 1;
  
  ...
}
```

In this example, the server is configured to allow only **one** connection (session). If one user connects, the next user to the same app will receive a 503 error page.